# Deleting list from another component in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm falling a bit short on exactly how props work when trying to setState between different components in a "simple" way in parent-child or sibling components (without redux or context).

I've read the documentation, maybe I'm just supersuper slow in understanding this as I'm trying to self-learn react/coding, but can someone please explain the following in "simple" words:

- in my parent.js I have all my logic for adding and removing a text and store it in a list
- in my child.js which is a page created by the parent.js as a part of the list I want to be able to remove the whole listitem. Right now that logic is written in the parent.js, so I kinda want to access this function from my child component.

**EDIT - I INCLUDED THE CODE FROM THE 2 MAIN COMPONENTS:**
**EDIT 2 - TEST CODE THAT RETURNS "onRemove is not a function":**

**Home.js**

```
const Home = ({navigation, route}) => {

const [lists, setLists] = useState([])
const [isVisible, setVisibility] = useState(true)

    const addItemToLists = (item) => {
        lists.push(item)
        setLists([...lists])
        setVisibility(false)
    }
    
    **const removeItemFromLists = (index) => {
        lists.splice(index,1) 
        setLists([...lists])
        console.log("removed")
        return(
            <EditList test={test} onRemove={removeItemFromLists}/>
        )
    }**
    
    const updateItemFromLists = (index,item) => {
        lists[index] = item
        setLists([...lists])
    }

return(

            <View style={styles.homeContainer}>

                <View style={styles.homeContainer2}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("Edit", {saveChanges: addItemToLists})}>
                        <Ionicons name="add-circle" size={60} color="black"/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>


                <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
                {!isVisible ? null : <Text>Add List-item</Text> }
                </View>

                <FlatList 
                data={lists}
                renderItem={({item: {title}, index})=>{
                    return(
                        <Listbutton 
                        title={title} 
                        navigation={navigation}
                        onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate("List", {title})}}
                        onOptions={()=>{navigation.navigate(
                            "Edit",
                            {title, saveChanges:(item)=>updateItemFromLists(index,item)})}}
                        onDelete={()=> removeItemFromLists(index)}
                        />
                    )
                }}
                />
                    
            </View>
    )
}
```

**EditList.js**

```
export default function EditList ({navigation, route,**test, onRemove**}){
    const [title, setTitle] = useState(route.params.title || "")
    const [isValid, setValidity] = useState(true)
    


    return(

    <View style={styles.editContainer}>
        <View>
     
        <TextInput
                    autoFocus={true} 
                    underlineColorAndroid={"transparent"}
                    selectionColor={"transparent"}
                    value={title}
                    onChangeText={(text)=>
                        {setTitle(text)
                            setValidity(true)
                        }}
                        placeholder={"Add header"}
                        maxLength={25}
                        style={styles.todoEditTextInput}
                        /> 

            <View style={{alignSelf: "center"}}> 
                {!isValid && <Text style={{color:"red"}}>Add list</Text>}
            </View>

             <TouchableOpacity
            style={{alignSelf: "center"}} 
            onPress={()=>{
                if (title.length > 0) {
                    route.params.saveChanges({title}) 
                    navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.goBack())
                } else {
                setValidity(false)
                }
            }}>
                <Ionicons name="checkmark-circle" size={50} style={{paddingLeft: 10,}}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>

        **<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onRemove(test)}>
                 <Ionicons name="trash" size={50} style={{paddingLeft: 10,}}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>**
```

Comment: can you create a codesandbox example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes I can post the code here aswell if that is easier, but I just want to hear what the "proper" way of achieving something like this would be. Don't need a direct answer to my code just the logic behind it if that makes sense?

Comment: StackOverflow kind of frowns on generic questions like this. You might be better served on a React discussion forum.

Comment: Alright I might add the specific code in a new question instead!

Comment: No need to make a new question! Just edit it into your current question!

Comment: I added the code from the 2 main components! so it is in the "editlist" where I want to put a button that triggers the delete-function, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So what you can do is pass your remove function as a prop to your child component, and call it when you want to execute it.

```
const ParentComponent = () => {

   const removeFromList = (someIdentifier) {
    // insert your list modification code here
   }

   return <ChildComponent someIdentifier={someIdentifier} onRemove={removeFromList} />

}

const ChildComponent = ({ someIdentifier, onRemove }) => (

 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onRemove(someIdentifier)} />  

)
```

I see you are using an index, so you could pass that in as your identifier - but please note that using indexes as keys is bad practice as you cannot guarantee that it will reference the same item in your list (especially now since you are removing items in a random order).

Comment: Thank you! I tried doing it like this: **Parent:**        const removeItemFromLists = (index) => {
            lists.splice(index,1) 
            setLists([...lists])
            console.log("removed")
            return(
                <EditList test={test} onRemove={removeItemFromLists}/>
            )
        } **and in the child:** export default function EditList ({navigation, route, test, onRemove}){ with a button like this:             <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onRemove(test)}>
But I get the error onRemove is not a function :( what am I not getting here

Comment: I think it will be best to create a codesandbox example, very hard to determine the issue when you paste the code in a comment like that :D

Comment: Ahh sorry, I updated the question, the parts I changed I wrapped between **, hope it doesn't look too messy haha :/

Comment: Don't return JSX from your removeItemFromLists function. Pass removeItemFromLists to the onDelete prop of your ListButton component (which is being rendered by your FlatList).

Comment: Do you mean inside the ListButton? I'm really confused sorry :(

Comment: You have an event on your ListButton called "onDelete" - why not use that instead of creating an entirely new component called EditList?

Comment: The EditList is a page created from Home and then instead of deleting the list in Home I want to delete the list from EditList hehe, but I set the state in Home for the list so this is where I think I confused myself haha